# Mouse hover outside menu button shows menu

Tags: html, css

I'm having an issue with the navigation menu. I'm trying to stop the menu showing when hovering outside the button. As you can see in the snippet, when moving the cursor to the left of the button the menu shows up rather than showing the menu when the cursor is over the button which I'm wanting to achieve.

Your help is much appreciated.

Here is the snippet:

```css
#btn-holder {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  position: static;
  z-index: 10;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

#btn-holder > .button {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #a137a7;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 18px 2px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  left: 14;
  bottom: 0;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  opacity: .4;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

#btn-holder > .button:hover {
  background-color: #732878;
  color: white;
}

#btn-holder > .menu {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #a137a7;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 59px;
  bottom: -300px;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;

    
}

.menu a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 8px 13px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family:'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    position:sticky;
   
}

.menu a:hover {
  background-color: #732878;
}

.menu > ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.menu p {
  margin: 0;
}

.menu p:after {
    content:"";
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    border-top: 1px solid #eee;
}

#btn-holder > .button:hover + .menu {
  opacity: .8;
  transistion-delay: 1s;
}

#btn-holder .menu:hover {
  opacity: .8;
  
}
```

```html
<div id="btn-holder">
  <div class="button">
    <img class="menu" src="http://static.tumblr.com/e2rgcy1/WhRod5hpn/open.png"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
     <li><a href="/"a target="_blank"><img class="followtmblr" src="http://static.tumblr.com/e2rgcy1/nz3ocovr0/tumblr-follow-icon.png"></a></li>
        
      <li><a href="/games"onclick="window.open(this.href, 'mywin', 
          'toolbar=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=1,height=620,width=700'); return false;"><img class="games" src="https://secure.static.tumblr.com/e2rgcy1/UrWocm53a/games-icon.png"></a></li> 
        
      <li><a href="/"a target="_blank"><img class="blog" src="https://secure.static.tumblr.com/e2rgcy1/i0Nocny7l/blog-icon.png"></a></li>
        
      <li><a href="/"a target="_blank"><img class="twit" src="https://secure.static.tumblr.com/e2rgcy1/liGockmkp/twitter-256.png"></a></li>
        
      <li><a href="/"a target="_blank"><img class="fb" src="http://static.tumblr.com/e2rgcy1/Ywiod4uar/fb-icon.png"></a></li>
        
      <li><a href="/"><img class="tc" src="https://secure.static.tumblr.com/e2rgcy1/vHdockmf2/tinychaticon.png"></a></li>
        
      <li><a href="/"><img class="refresh" src="https://secure.static.tumblr.com/e2rgcy1/4Yxocknow/refresh.png"></a></li>
        
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: just add `visibility:hidden;` to your `.menu` class and on hover change it to `visibility: visible;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are hovering over the hidden element that's why it appears you have to move it out of window and on hover position it where you want it to appear

```css
#btn-holder {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  position: static;
  z-index: 10;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

#btn-holder > .button {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #a137a7;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 18px 2px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  left: 14;
  bottom: 0;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  opacity: .4;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

#btn-holder > .button:hover {
  background-color: #732878;
  color: white;
}

#btn-holder > .menu {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #a137a7;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: -100px;
  bottom: -500px;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.menu a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 8px 13px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family:'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    position:sticky;
   
}

.menu a:hover {
  background-color: #732878;
}

.menu > ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.menu p {
  margin: 0;
}

.menu p:after {
    content:"";
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    border-top: 1px solid #eee;
}

#btn-holder > .button:hover + .menu {
  opacity: .8;
  left: 59px;
}

#btn-holder .menu:hover {
  opacity: .8;
  left: 59px;
}
```

```html
<div id="btn-holder">
  <div class="button">
    <img class="menu" src="http://static.tumblr.com/e2rgcy1/WhRod5hpn/open.png"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
     <li><a href="/"a target="_blank"><img class="followtmblr" src="http://static.tumblr.com/e2rgcy1/nz3ocovr0/tumblr-follow-icon.png"></a></li>
        
      <li><a href="/games"onclick="window.open(this.href, 'mywin', 
          'toolbar=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=1,height=620,width=700'); return false;"><img class="games" src="https://secure.static.tumblr.com/e2rgcy1/UrWocm53a/games-icon.png"></a></li> 
        
      <li><a href="/"a target="_blank"><img class="blog" src="https://secure.static.tumblr.com/e2rgcy1/i0Nocny7l/blog-icon.png"></a></li>
        
      <li><a href="/"a target="_blank"><img class="twit" src="https://secure.static.tumblr.com/e2rgcy1/liGockmkp/twitter-256.png"></a></li>
        
      <li><a href="/"a target="_blank"><img class="fb" src="http://static.tumblr.com/e2rgcy1/Ywiod4uar/fb-icon.png"></a></li>
        
      <li><a href="/"><img class="tc" src="https://secure.static.tumblr.com/e2rgcy1/vHdockmf2/tinychaticon.png"></a></li>
        
      <li><a href="/"><img class="refresh" src="https://secure.static.tumblr.com/e2rgcy1/4Yxocknow/refresh.png"></a></li>
        
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, the only issue in your snippet is that I'm not able to select any menu items as the menu just disappears when trying to select them,

Comment: than you have to apply the position to the elements hover state too i will adjust my code wait

Comment: i had to change the transition because with the delay there was no time for moving the pointer to the icons but it looks nice :D

Comment: no problem please mark that my answer solved your problem much appreciated :)

Comment: I've run in to a little issue when changing the `left: 14;
  top: 320px;` in `#btn-holder > .button {` and `left: 59px;
  bottom: -50px;` in `#btn-holder > .menu {` the transition does not work, See updated snippet.

Comment: and why do you want to do that that puts it to a compleatly wrong position

Comment: Because the position of the button and the menu are slightly higher on my website. When the position of the button and the menu is changed the menu seems to  resort back to the same behaviour as seem in my first snippet.

Comment: did you also change the transition statement? transition needs to be on #btn-holder > .menu { transition: 0.5s;
}not on hover

Comment: It's seems to be there in the right place in `#btn-holder > .menu`. If you see your snippet  I just edited in a full page you can see what I mean by where I have changed the position but the transition no longer functions,

Comment: you have to move it with only two attributes. Switching from bottom to top or right to left doesn't trigger an animation only if you change values of bottom and left